# Android: Dyslexic content uris. The same file returns two separate content uri IDs with swapped digits

Tags: android, uri

Using a chooser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.select)), GET_URI);
```

I get an audio file. I take that Uri and save it in a local database to access later. I found that for a certain song selected the content uri would return a null value when you tried to create a MediaPlayer using it. I tried to get the content uri for that same song again to see what would happen, and sure enough:

Old, broken content uri: `content://media/external/audio/media/2478`

New, working content uri: `content://media/external/audio/media/2487`

Identical save for the last two digits being swapped. The method to obtain this Uri has not changed between my two attempts. Is this a known problem? My google and SO searched yielded no results. But this is a problem if content uris have a habit of becoming dyslexic, because there is no real way to remedy the problem short of re-obtaining the song's content uri, which must be done manually since there is no way to reference the song's file path with the wrong content uri.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dyslexic some of them are!

Some of the fields exposed by the Content Providers are cached. And so they are not guaranteed to be fresh. Since you did not specify the means by which you obtained this URI, I cannot tell if it is a cached value.

You can look into the code and figure it out yourself.

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/provider/MediaStore.java

Comment: Yes, a content Uri I set yesterday once again has failed to be accurate with this same problem. I didn't realize content uris can sometimes change value! I think for the future I am going to use a file Uri instead when saving the location of the song.

Comment: Make sure that you read up the documentation on the Uris that you use.